# XSLT 1.0 libxslt output escaped character: how?

Tags: firefox, escaping

How can I add `&#xD;` as text when using libxslt?
Or, alternatively, make all browsers including Firefox display linefeeds in `td/title` elements properly by generating a different output?

The xslt code I use:

```
<td>
    <xsl:attribute name="title">
        <xsl:for-each select="input/item">
            <xsl:if test="position()!=1"><xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text></xsl:if>:<xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:attribute>
</td>
```

This works fine when applying Saxon9he, for instance leading to

```
<td title="item1&#xD;item2&#xD;item3"/>
```

But when I use `libxslt` (part of php) as XSLT 1.0 processor, and run the same code as above, I get real linefeeds in the result file:

```
<td title="item1
item2
item3"/>
```

causing Firefox to display the tooltip incorrectly (without linefeeds).

So I assumed I had to add `disable-output-escaping` attribute to `<xsl:text>` as follows:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&#xD;</xsl:text>
```

but this has no effect.

Comment: This is a bug in FF -- IE, Safari and Chrome display the tooltips OK.

Comment: I know - so I wish to add `&#xD;` instances in order to have all browsers display OK - bugged or not.

Comment: There's nothing that can be done: FF displays the tooltips incorrectly even when the attribute value is: `item1&#xD;item2&#xD;item3`

Comment: Curious. I just tried this in FF and it displays just fine. What version of Firefox are you using? I'm using 12.0. Incidentally, have you tried using `&#xA;` instead?

Comment: Browser user agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0 so I guess it's FF version 10.0 - I will upgrade then. And yes I tried &#xA; too.

Comment: So this is strictly FF question.

Comment: It seems to be indeed - I upgraded to FF 13 just now and all is OK. I will close the question accordingly - thnks all for helping!

Comment: Answer it yourself; this information may be useful to others, it's worth keeping it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the conclusion from comments and tests is that it is a bug in Firefox but not in all versions: 9.01 does not even display `&#xD`; right; 10.0 does not display linefeed but does display `&#xD;` as a linefeed, and 12.0/13.0 display both correctly.

Case closed.